# Data Sheet Inconsistencies with TI LM2672N

Tags: datasheet

I'm a novice with Electrical Engineering, and am having a difficult time coping with inconsistencies in a particular data sheet.

[Texas Instruments LM2672N-5.0 Data Sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2672.pdf)

Like many data sheets, TI provides example circuits for using their chip. However, unlike other data sheets I've seen (so far), it's riddled with inconsistencies, such as capacitor sizes, placement, etc:

[image: Cb Pin Connection Description]

[image: Circuit diagram showing different capacitance value]

Even within the same diagram, there are inconsistencies:

[image: Inconsistent diagram]

How should one interpret these diagrams and recommended component values?

Comment: Well, 0.01uF is 10nF so that is a non-issue. True, there are some discrepancies, but work through the desing guide to figure out what range of input voltage and output current matches the part values. Capacitor value difference is easily explained by they being a different type, like electrolytic versus tantalum.

Comment: @Justme I just now saw the "design guide", didn't scroll down far enough! I'll need to work my circuit's values through and see what values come out. Any idea why TI doesn't remain consistent in their diagrams and descriptions throughout the data sheet? Is it on purpose, to emphasize you need to calculate your own values?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to calculate anything, the point of these simple switcher family devices is that you can pick parts from the charts. Most likely some of the values are leftovers from previous datasheets, it is not unheard of that there are issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example schematics are not intended to be copied verbatim, necessarily, from the datasheet. They can be copied from the datasheet, but also an understanding must be used as it is the designers responsibility to understand what the design does.

However, this datasheet is not great, and it looks like someone fell asleep on the job. The lower schematic should have the same value for the inductor as the value listed on the example and they even give a part number which has a value of 68uH (not 47).

The input caps value doesn't matter as much as it's just a bypass cap. But the output caps value does matter as it affects the feedback loop and whether the converter functions, so they should have not created uncertainty on that one.

One could contact TI on their errors, but they are very poor on customer feedback and really don't care from the experiences I've had.

I would use their TINA tool to simulate the converter to give an idea if it will function or not (DC DC converters can have issues with PCB parasitics and may not work with poor PCB layouts.)

Comment: Output capacitance value depends on if it is through hole electrolytic or SMD tantalum, they do mention it in the datasheet.

Comment: Yeah, the difference between the two would affect the ESR, but ripple on the input isn't usually a big problem in most designs (unless is is really large).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is exceptionally bad. There are several other inconsistencies as well, such as a table 7 , with capacitors being labeled as inductors.

But you need to consider the application curves on page 19 to fit your circuit. Just picking the application example might not work as intended.

These are simply to select your input voltage along the y-axis and follow the x-axis until you get to your output current, and then select the inductor in that region.

Comment: No, you are just reading the table wrong. Table 7 helps you pick a capacitor based on what inductor you have, e.g. for 5V out with 47uH inductor, you use capacitor C4. Next table tells you what possible choises you have for capacitor C4, based on which kind of capacitor you want.